# Why does the first element of the function is removed when executing other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Solution: You cant use the same button group name even if they are under different IDs even if they seem to operate separately.

I have two different functions called `motivators()` and `barriers()` in jQuery.

Whenever I execute one of the functions, it scans through the HTML for the given element ID, gets the value and stores it in an array. If I run the second function then it does the same to a different column of data, then stores the data in a different array in the second function.

the function `radios("motivators or barriers")` handle which table should be inspected for any data.

The code for `motivators()` is the following:

```
function motivators() {
    var motLen = 0;
    var motTotal = 0;

    radios( "motivators" );

    var motivatorsArr = [];

    for ( var i = 1; i <= 17; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 1; j <= 4; j++ ) {
            var button = $( "#rad" + "" + i + "" + j );
            if ( button . is( ":checked" ) ) {
                motivatorsArr . push( button . val() );
                button . parents( "tr" ) . css( "opacity", "0" ) . delay( 750 ) . hide( 0 );
                motLen++;
            }
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
        if ( motivatorsArr[ i ] !== undefined ) {
            motTotal += parseInt( motivatorsArr[ i ] );
        }
    }
    console.log("motivators: " + motivatorsArr,motLen,motTotal)
    return {motLen: motLen, motTotal: motTotal};
}
```

`barriers()` is basically the same but with different variables

```
function barriers() {
    var barLen = 0;
    var barTotal = 0;

    radios( "barriers" );

    var barriersArr = [];

    for ( var i = 1; i <= 17; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 1; j <= 4; j++ ) {
            var button = $( "#rad00" + "" + i + "" + j );
            if ( button . is( ":checked" ) ) {
                barriersArr . push( button . val() );
                button . parents( "tr" ) . css( "opacity", "0" ) . delay( 750 ) . hide( 0 );
                barLen++;
            }
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
        if ( barriersArr[ i ] !== undefined ) {
            barTotal += parseInt( barriersArr[ i ] );
        }
    }
    console.log("barriers: " + barriersArr,barLen,barTotal)
    return {barLen: barLen, barTotal: barTotal};
}
```

the values I need to get are radio buttons which I iterate through with the 1 to 17 and the four button in one group are the 1 to 4.

Basically whenever I run the two functions each time the first function pops the first element of the array and vice versa. It drives me crazy that I can not find out what is the problem with the given functions.

Changing one radio button results in

```
$( "#motivators input, #barriers input" ).on( "change", function () {
    total();
} );
```

and `total()` contains the other two function to run like:

```
function total() {
    var mot = motivators();
    var bar = barriers();
}
```

The result of trying to use the first 5 radio button groups in the different tables. First 5 button from motivators, then first 5 buttons from barriers, notice how the length of the motivators decrease each time the function is executed. And it is true the other direction, if I were to use 5 buttons from motivators, then barriers would go to zero.
https://kepkuldes.com/images/8c1b260794808153375bfd494c385fa5.png

EDIT:

Here is the code for the radio buttons
motivators radio button group 11

```
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad111" name="r11" value="0">
                        <label for="rad111"></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad112" name="r11" value="2">
                        <label for="rad112"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad113" name="r11" value="5">
                        <label for="rad113"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad114" name="r11" value="15">
                        <label for="rad114"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
```

barriers radio group number 11

```
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad00111" name="r11" value="0">
                        <label for="rad00111"></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad00112" name="r11" value="2">
                        <label for="rad00112"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad00113" name="r11" value="5">
                        <label for="rad00113"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="rad00114" name="r11" value="15">
                        <label for="rad00114"></label>
                        <span class="contLabel"></span>
                    </li>
```

To make a difference between the groups, one of the table radio button groups are called `#rad` and the group number, and the other is called `#rad00` and the group number. I asked my friend and brother to recheck for me if I had a typo but could not find any. The iterations are quite straight forward (for me at least I accept a simpler and faster solution if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the name attribute for the radio buttons:  #rad0011 and #rad11 .

You probably have groups of 8 radio buttons with the same attribute name. 4 buttons from the #rad00** column and 4 from the #rad** column

Comment: So having the same name under a different ID is the same? Like one is `#motivators r11` is the same as `#barriers r11` ?

Comment: Yes it is by name not id. glad I could help :)